# Simple http request in gnustep's objective c not working

Tags: objective-c, http, gnustep

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

main() {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]; 
        NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url                
            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData  
                timeoutInterval:60]; 

        NSURLResponse *response; 
        NSError *error; 
        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error]; 
        NSLog(@"Data were download below:\n%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding]); 
}
```

run the executable ->
Data were download below:
[null]

Why?

Comment: Obvious question: what does the `error` say?

Comment: if (error != nil) [error userInfo] -> segmentation fault

Comment: Now that’s interesting. Even plain `NSLog(@"%@", error)` does that?

Comment: yes, resulted in segt fault too.

Comment: but, the http req/resp appeared correctly by tcpdump.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried allocating the request and error?

NSURLResponse *response = [[NSURLResponce alloc] init];

NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];